# Has Thor ever given his power to others the same way he did in Love & Thunder?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-love-and-thunder

In "Thor: Love & Thunder", we saw Thor giving his powers to the kidnapped children for one time only to fight the shadow monsters.

I was wondering if he ever given his powers before the same way in a previous battler or fight against enemies.

Comment: Just in the MCU? Not that I can remember.

Comment: Yeah, only in the MCU.

Comment: From memory, doesn't he use Zeus' lightning bolt to do it?

Comment: I just don't know why my question is being voted down

Comment: @RogueJedi he was holding and talking to the bolt, but he used his other arm to give them the thunder and said "Thor's power".

Answer (score 4):

The brief answer is yes. Thor shares his powers in almost exactly the same way earlier in *Love and Thunder*, e.g. **by enchanting a magical weapon**. Speaking to Mjölnir he gives his powers to Jane in the event that she needs its protection. Since she meets Thor's criteria for worthiness (someone willing to devote their wellbeing to helping others) she is also able to wield Mjölnir and possess the power of Thor.

> **Thor:** *I need you to promise me, you'll always protect her.*
> [beat] *I love you too, buddy.*
>
> **Korg:** [VO] *And love that deep has a way of becoming magical.*
>
> [Mjölnir glows to show that an enchantment has occurred]
>
> [image]

The fact that Thor has Zeus' thunderbolt (certainly one of the most powerful weapons seen thus far in the MCU) is probably what gave him sufficient *oomph* to enchant thirty weapons simultaneously.

Comment: but has he outside love and thunder?

Comment: @shanu - No. His father did it in *Thor*

Comment: Sorry I will not accept this as an answer as I am asking about times before this movie.